Need help with understanding で Situation/Condition particle
入れ違いで亜美さんが出て行ったところです。
''Ami just went out as we passed each-other''
(Not my translation)
So this was my understanding of it:
[Indicates situation where something else happened]
(It highlights the situation where the action took place)
So my question is, if で is situational based in this context, how would you parse / translate it?
で ~ 出て行ったところです
(I'm using this as a basis to parse.)
Since something happened ''just went out'' would で indicate the time of the situation?
''Ami Just went out when/at the moment of us passing'' (?)
Or is it
''Ami just came out at the situation/event of us passing''
The reason I am asking is because the Situation/Condition particle is extremely confusing to me and I've been stuck for a couple of weeks still not getting it entirely.
Question as a follow up from this:
Function of で in this sentence: 「入れ違いで亜美さんが出て行ったところです」
[EDIT]
The intent was not to ask a ''stupid'' question. I just don't know how to parse this particular rule.
[UPDATE]
I think I got it now:
[It indicates what happened during the situation hence why ''as we were passing'' works. It is because the action happened ''as/while we were doing something'']

"Or is it" - I don't understand the distinction you're trying to draw; it seems to mean effectively the same thing either way. Translation is an art, and Japanese and English grammars work fundamentally differently from each other - so you're always going to be stuck with approximations.

Also, in the context of the previous question, it seems that a third party was saying this to the listener (who was presumably looking for Ami).

Context wise as you mentioned I got that, it's mostly just the usage of the で here I was confused about since I found the explanation of it being ''situational'' to be too vague for me. Again I'm just trying to learn. But if both of my interpretations seemed somewhat right then at least it seems like I'm on the right track.

@KarlKnechtel Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. This で doesn't obviously fit any of the main uses I know of, but maybe that's because I don't really understand 入れ違い either. I find the English translation equally perplexing (and English is my native language).

@KarlKnechtel The distinction was how they were framed but those examples now looking back at them the nuance does not match and the translation is awkward. That's why I asked but now I get it.

入れ違いで adverbially modifies 出て行った, and you're correct that this で is a situation/condition particle used like this. It marks the "manner" of the action of getting out.
Here, 入れ違い is a noun that means something complicated like this. Unfortunately, there is no exact English match for either 入れ違い or で, but you can parse the sentence like this:

入れ違いで亜美さんが出て行った。

Ami went out 入れ違い(-ish)-ly.
Ami went out in an 入れ違い manner.
Ami went out in a just-as-one-person-enters-another-leaves manner.



I think this will help a lot of people when they find this. It isn't always easy to parse so I appreciate this answer.
